# Which operating system for my first VPS?

Tags: server, vps, java, operating-system

I'm starting to host my first web application on a VPS, but I don't yet have any experience managing a server. I want to minimize the costs of hosting but also reduce the hassles which a 1 man startup can bear with.

I'm not sure what would a better choice for me in terms of the operating system for my VPS. My web application is based in Java (JSF) using Cassandra (NoSQL) database. I am planning to learn the server side stuff for few weeks before I bring my sites into production. Could you recommend an OS for my first VPS?

--

Answer (score 2):

I use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS personally.

Some use a more server-oriented distro of 'Nix, but having used Desktop Ubuntu for years, the server-side is pretty much identical, obviously without a UI. There are also (from what I see) a lot more snippets of example commands and code regarding ubuntu on the web than other distros.

Java runs fine and is easy to set up, I'm not sure about Cassandra.

However, at the end of the day, they're all about equal for a small-scale web app hosting situation such as yours. Install a distro and have a play around - I'm sure you'll get a feel for it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed there are a lot of CentOS server for webapps out there. It isn't really hard to maintain, since it has a nice community. Basically CentOS aims to be 100% binary upstream compatible (with RedHat Enterprise Linux that is). Only without the RHEL branding.

Comment: After going through this thread (http://serverfault.com/questions/53954/centos-vs-ubuntu) I am a bit skeptical looking at centos

Comment: What is it in that post what makes you skeptical? The only thing I see is hardware support, but if you are going to run a VPS it is either supported or not.